# Not Equal To condition in data.table join

Tags: r, join, data.table

**Problem**

I'm trying to join two tables, with several conditions. I would like to add a Not Equal To condition.

**What I tried**

I tried to use `!=` and <> but nothing works, do you know how to do it ?

**Example**

```
A <- data.table(c("a","a","b","c","d"),c(1,2,3,4,5),c("aa","ab","aa","cd","aa"))
B <- data.table(c("a","a","b","c","d"),c(1,1,5,4,7),c("aa","ab","aa","cd","aa"),c("yes","yes","no","yes","no"))

Jdt <- A[B,on= .(V1,V2,A.V3 != i.V3), `:=`(V4 = i.V4)][is.na(V4), V4 :=0][]
```

**EDIT Desired output**

```
   V1 V2 V3  V4
1:  a  1 aa   0
2:  a  2 ab yes
3:  b  3 aa  no
4:  c  4 cd   0
5:  d  5 aa  no
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
A[B,on=c("V1","V3"),`:=`(V42 = i.V4)][V2==i.V2,V4:="0"][,i.V2:=NULL][]
```

I'd like to rename the columns during the join, bu i get this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i.V2' not found
```

here's the output i'm looking for

```
   V1 V2 V3  V42
1:  a  1 aa   0
2:  a  2 ab yes
3:  b  3 aa  no
4:  c  4 cd   0
5:  d  5 aa  no
```

Comment: You should at least describe your desired output. Your final goal is not much clear to me, but maybe you could join A and B only on `V1, V2` and then select the rows in which `V3` and `i.V3` differ. Something like `A[B,on= c("V1","V2")][V3!=i.V3]`.

Comment: The possibility for *not-equal-to* joins (`!=`) is not implemented yet, see [this feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1801) on GitHub.

Comment: @nicola  I edited my question adding the desired output. Sorry for this.

Comment: @Jaap I find performance of `data.table` and am looking to create permutations (without replacement) using natural syntax (without chaining). Do we have an eta for this feature please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are actually joining on `V1` and `V3` and checking conditions on `V2`. Try this:

```
A[B,on=c("V1","V3")][V2==i.V2,V4:="0"][,i.V2:=NULL][]
#   V1 V2 V3  V4
#1:  a  1 aa   0
#2:  a  2 ab yes
#3:  b  3 aa  no
#4:  c  4 cd   0
#5:  d  5 aa  no
```

Comment: It would be better to modify A in place rather than making a new table, I guess

Comment: @Frank i think that it can be done like that `A <-A[B,on=c("V1","V3")][V2==i.V2,V4:="0"][,i.V2:=NULL][] `

Comment: @OrhanYazar By "in place", I mean "by reference". If you're not familiar with that feature, it's mentioned in the first couple package vignettes https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: @nicola I got a problem. I tried to do this: `A[B,on=c("V1","V3"),':='(V42=i.V4)][V2==i.V2,V4:="0"][,i.V2:=NULL][]` but i'm getting `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i.item' not found`